# C++ class function chain-calling compilation error

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where i was given c++ code that has multiple test functions, and i have to write the ***stri*** class with all the functions necesary for these tests to pass. I am having difficulty with one particular test about chain linking.

```
void Lab4Tests::testChainedSet() {
stri greet = "Hello";
assert(0==strcmp("Hello", greet.get()), "testChainedSet", "internal representation error");

greet.set("Hi").set("Buna");
assert(0==strcmp("Buna", greet.get()), "testChainedSet", "set failed");
}
```

My function inside the class that I wrote to solve this test is the following

```
char* set(const char* s){
    len=strlen(s);
    repres=new char(len+1);
    strcpy(repres,s);
    return repres;
    }
```

I get an error when compiling the code

```
error: request for member 'set' in 'greet.stri::set(((const char*)"Hi"))', which is of non-class type 'char*'|
```

I dont understand chain linking that well, I would appreciate if somebody could point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how you can call `.set()` on a char array which is what your function returns. Chaining involves member functions that usually return `*this`.

Comment: The compiler tells you that you can't call member functions on `char*`. Chain member functions can be invoked only in chains that return object references, not pointers to primitive values.

Comment: As an aside, if `repres` is a member variable of type `char *`, you have a memory leak - `set` will need to `delete []` the old value of `repres` before it assigns a new value.  This is more complicated because you really ought to handle `foo.set(foo.get())` - which if you do it naively will delete the value you are trying to copy.  (The solution is to allocate memory into a temporary, copy the value into the temporary, and *then* free the member. - And make the whole thing exception safe by making repres be a smart pointer like std::unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to chain calls you need to return a reference to the `this` object.

For instance

```
stri& set(const char* s)
{
    repres = std::strdup(s);
    return *this;
}
```

I've taken the liberty of simplifying your string duplication. I haven't fixed the memory leak that you will get if you call `set` when `repres` already contains dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Note that not all platforms offer `std::strdup` (it's a Posix function which is present in the dynamic memory TR.)

Comment: I'd expect it to be present on all major platforms.

Comment: So would I.  I just like to be aware of when I am depending on something beyond what the standard guarantees.